# Enable ssh service from command line (single user mode)

Tags: macos, command-line, unix

How can i enable the ssh service in the single user mode?

I know how to do it in Terminal:

```
systemsetup -setremotelogin on
```

How can i do it in the single user mode? And if i reboot the system that it's still activated?
I tried this: [Enable SSH on a Mac in single user mode](https://superuser.com/questions/442841/enable-ssh-on-a-mac-in-single-user-mode)
But it didn't work.
I tried:

```
/sbin/fsck -fy
/sbin/mount -uw /
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.opendirectoryd.plist
systemsetup -setremotelogin on
```

Then it say's something like: connection invalidated. I'l check on that right after i post this.

So can please anyone explain to me how can i enable/activate ssh via the single user mode

Comment: It say's: 2013-10-12 01:25:08.366 systemsetup[13:1703]Connection with distnoted server was invalidated NEWLINE 2013-10-12 01:25:38.720 systemsetup[13:707] Cannot call DServiceEnabled:enabled without first being authenticated

Comment: still no answer?

Comment: guys... why does nobody know that?